# Communicate between shared hosted web site and Windows service

Tags: php, sockets, ftp

What is the best way to communicate between a shared hosted PHP site (on GoDaddy) and a Windows service on computer at another site?  
I would like to build a site that will allow a customer to schedule tasks on their server, and then look at logs of those tasks that have run. The problem is getting the scheduling information from the web site to the server, and then pulling log information from the server back to my web site. I will have access to the server to install a service (not sure what language would be best to build the service).
I’ve thought of two options. I wonder if either of these two options makes sense or if a third option would be better.
Option 1 - Sockets:
My PHP code would use fsockopen and fputs
My Windows service would open a socket and receive the text.
The problem I see is potential firewall difficulties. Also, the two would have to open sockets at the same time.
Option 2 – FTP:
The windows service would periodically (once a minute or so) open an FTP connection to my GoDaddy site and place a file and also check to see if there is a file to pull down.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Em, that architecture is a _very_ bad idea when you look at it from a security point of view.

Comment: Option 1 will not cause any firewall problems. Also you only require one single socket, communication can be bidirectional with that. This is a typical communication behavior on the internet. Easiest would be a simple https communication.

Comment: Option 2 should be ruled out immediately. FTP is an unencrypted protocol, everyone can see and steal the password, thus taking control over that MS-Windows system and do whatever he likes. No way a sane administrator would agree to that.

Comment: But anyway: all approaches mean you store and manage administrative tasks of an internal system out in the internet where it is vulnerable and cannot be relied on. That _is_ a bad idea.

Comment: I see no generally bad in that idea. There are several scenarios where it will be necessary to communicate data from local networks to a public server. I would use the second scenario, using SFTP, or even better HTTPS meaning you setup a web service on your public server secured by credentials and HTTPS encryption that provides the functionality to upload the log files - periodically

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. It sounds like both options have their merit, but security is the main concern. For my project I have no need for real time communication, only synch of data, so whichever way I go it will use a secure communication.